# Require in superclass' init block raises IllegalArgumentException [Kotlin]

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-null-safety

Good Morning Kotlin gurus.

I have an inheritance structure in which the abstract superclass implements some shared of data checks. The compiler does not complain, but upon execution an IllegalArgumentException is thrown by the JVM

#### The Code

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val foo = Child("NOT_BLANK")
}

abstract class Parent(
    open val name: String = "NOT_BLANK"
) {
    init {
        require(name.isNotBlank()) { "Firstname must not be blank" }
    }
}

data class Child(
    override val name: String = "NOT_BLANK"
) : Parent(
    name = name
)
```

#### The exception looks as follows

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter specified as non-null is null: method kotlin.text.StringsKt__StringsJVMKt.isBlank, parameter $receiver
at kotlin.text.StringsKt__StringsJVMKt.isBlank(StringsJVM.kt)
at com.systemkern.Parent.<init>(DataClassInheritance.kt:24)
at com.systemkern.Child.<init>(DataClassInheritance.kt:30)
at com.systemkern.DataClassInheritanceKt.main(DataClassInheritance.kt:17)
```

Thanks for your time

all the best

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On `name.isNotBlank()`, you should be getting a lint warning like this:

> Accessing non-final property name in constructor

You're accessing the `name` property at the time when the `Parent` is being constructed, however, `name` is overridden in `Child`. This override means that internally, both the `Parent` and `Child` classes have private fields for `name`, and since the `Parent` constructor is the first thing called when a `Child` is created, the `Child`'s `name` won't be initialized yet, but the check in `Parent` will access the `Child`'s override of the property when it does the check.

That might sound complicated, here are the relevant parts of the decompiled bytecode of your example (simplified):

```
public abstract class Parent {
    @NotNull
    private final String name;

    @NotNull
    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public Parent(@NotNull String name) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
        if(!StringsKt.isBlank(this.getName())) { // uses getName, which is overridden in
                                                 // Child, so Child's field is returned
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Firstname must not be blank");
        }
    }
}

public final class Child extends Parent {
    @NotNull
    private final String name;

    @NotNull
    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public Child(@NotNull String name) {
        super(name); // calls super constructor
        this.name = name; // sets own name field
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking the time and answering my question :)... Is there a mice way to circumvent this problem (except creating a separate check method)

Comment: Depends on how you actually use these classes. If you need to access the `name` property through `Parent` but you also need `name` in the constructor of `Child` for the data class features, then you're in a bit of a trouble. Perhaps you can rename the property in `parent` to something else, so you're not overriding it, but duplicating it in every subclass and validating the copy of it that's in `Parent`.

Answer (score 2):

Some code to understand execution order of kotlin initializers[1]

```
  open class Parent {
    private val a = println("Parent.a")

    constructor(arg: Unit=println("Parent primary constructor default argument")) {
        println("Parent primary constructor")
    }

    init {
        println("Parent.init")
    }

     private val b = println("Parent.b")
    }

    class Child : Parent {
    val a = println("Child.a")

    init {
        println("Child.init 1")
    }

    constructor(arg: Unit=println("Child primary constructor default argument")) : super() {
        println("Child primary constructor")
    }

    val b = println("Child.b")

    constructor(arg: Int, arg2:Unit= println("Child secondary constructor default argument")): this() {
        println("Child secondary constructor")
    }

    init {
        println("Child.init 2")
    }
   }
```

Output for Child(1)

```
Child secondary constructor default argument
Child primary constructor default argument
Parent primary constructor default argument
Parent.a
Parent.init
Parent.b
Parent primary constructor
Child.a
Child.init 1
Child.b
Child.init 2
Child primary constructor
Child secondary constructor
```

Essentially, Parent.init is being called before the actual object is constructed and hence the Exception is thrown.

Ref : 
[1] https://medium.com/keepsafe-engineering/an-in-depth-look-at-kotlins-initializers-a0420fcbf546